# Is PyDAQmx or similar available for mac?

Tags: python, labview

As a mac user I would like to use a NI-DAQmx on a mac but without the classical LabVIEW, hopefully with python or Matlab.

I only found this [PyDAQmx](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDAQmx/), but it is just for windows and linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use NI hardware from python on a Mac, you need a driver with a C API.

Unfortunately, NI-DAQmx is not available for Mac, but NI provides the **NI-DAQmx Base** driver. This driver is a subset of NI-DAQmx in two ways: the supported devices and, for a given device, the supported hardware features. See the ReadMe [1] for the list of devices and features that are supported, but in general, the PCI/PCIe E and M Series devices are supported, as are the USB 621x devices; notable absences are the X Series devices and Compact DAQ (cDAQ).

NI-DAQmx Base has a C API, and it appears you can use it with PyDAQmx 1.3.2 [2].

If you are willing to forgo python and use LabVIEW, NI has a driver for the NI myDAQ device [3]. This driver **is** NI-DAQmx, but only supports that one device.

### References

> **[1] NI-DAQmx Base for Mac**
>   
> http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-15.0/5648/en/
>
> **[2] PyDAQmx 1.3.2**
>   
> https://github.com/clade/PyDAQmx/releases/tag/v1.3.2
>
> **[3] Getting Started With NI-DAQmx for myDAQ on Mac OS X**
>   
> http://www.ni.com/white-paper/52345/en/

Comment: I know this is a year and a half later, but the current version of PyDAQmx (1.3.2) does search for PyDAQmx Base on OS X (tested on 10.10 and 10.11) - you don't need to add your own implementation now. Be sure to install a version of NIDAQmx Base that matches your architecture (I installed 3.7.0 and it was only 32bit which worked on a 32bit version of python, and then found 15.0.0 floating around the NI website which mysteriously installed a 64bit version that worked with 64bit python).

Comment: Thanks! I updated the answer to reflect your research and report.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have installed the driver, ni-daqmx-base, you could use PyDAQmx on Mac.

2) Nidaqmx cannot used on Mac, even though ni-daqmx-base driver installed.